# How to pop up application using windows services c#

Tags: c#, windows-services

I want to pop up an application using windows services.

Right now the code that I am using is:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(@" ");
```

That code does not pop up the application when I start running the services.

Comment: As @ThorstenDirrmar indicated, it is purely a session issue. If you don't know what is a session then you have to study Windows more. Session isolation requires you to split your application into a Windows service and a desktop app running in user sessions. Then interprocess communication can inform the desktop application to prompt the user.

Comment: Review this entry on [GUI services](http://www.coretechnologies.com/WindowsServices/FAQ.html#GUIServices) and consider adjusting your design accordingly...

Answer (score 1):

You can not do that. User session interaction has been removed since Windows Vista. The process would be started in the session that the service runs in, which per definition is not desktop interactive.

What you *can* do is run windowless console-only tools.

---

Long story: Before Vista all services ran in the same session as the first logged in user ("session 0"). Since this is a security issue, this was changed in Vista, where a dedicated session ("session 0") is active from the start for services. The first user logs into session 1, the next user into session 2 etc.

Due to the separation of these sessions it is no longer possible to create desktop interactive services - there *is no* desktop session for services.

This also means you can not display message boxes or run desktop interactive tools in session 0 - there's nobody who can see them.

Comment: Not very accurate, as it should be the "session isolation", https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/dn653293(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: May not be accurate, but is still correct :-) Thanks for providing the link though.

Answer (score 0):

Is that the exact code that you're using?

If so you're not actually giving the process anything to start, just an empty string. You need to pass it the name of the executable.

For example:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(@"C:\Windows\System32\notepad.exe");
```

If this is not the exact code, please post modify the question with the exact code.